# Screenshots with Idea Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ddms

how can i capture the screenshot of an app using ddms from intellij Idea?

I have been using intellij for some time and i find it very useful.
though i couldnt find a way to make it work.

Could any one please tell me if this is possible from within the IDE itself?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**UPDATE**: `Screen Capture` feature was added in IntelliJ IDEA 13 (and Android Studio):

[image: Screen Capture]

It's available in the `Android` tool window (View -> Tool Windows -> Android).

---

*Answer for older IDEA versions:*

IDEA doesn't have this feature. If you are on Windows, you can try something like [Android Commander](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=597098) or use DDMS directly.

New IDEA versions have a menu shortcut for **Monitor** (DDMS replacement in recent Android SDK versions):

[image: Monitor]

After running **Android Debug Monitor**, use the **Screen capture** button:

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: how to use ddms directly: http://www.srtsolutions.com/taking-android-emulator-screenshots-without-eclipse

Comment: My screenshots were empty when the "Use Host GPU" option was enabled for the AVD. Unchecking that option solved the empty screenshot problem but the render quality was very bad, so i ended up taking screenshots of the AVD window...

Comment: I want to confirm that the Screen Capture button works perfectly for taking screenshots in the free version of Genymotion. Very useful.

Answer (score 9):

In IntelliJ IDEA 11, Tools => Android => DDMS.
Then press Ctrl (Command) + S, then Save