# Intelij idea how to make print screen from device

Tags: android, intellij-idea, screenshot

I just start to use IntelliJ IDEA. Before It I used Eclipse.

There is a nice thing, you can get a screenshot from your device:

[image: Screenshot of the functionality in Eclipse]

Is there a similar functionality available in IntelliJ?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/11257514/6309 help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DDMS directly. (This is already what Eclipse does.)

In the [Android SDK]/tools folder there is a file named *ddms.bat*.

Running that file will launch **Dalvik Debug Monitor**.

Using *Device* menu in this monitor, choose *Screen Capture* after selecting your current emulator.

Now you can take screenshots using *Save* and *Refresh* buttons.

Comment: http://take.ms/Dlg Don't have it(

Comment: No, [Android SDK] directory is where you downloaded the Android SDK. You should reach that through the file system.