# Why is [PrtSc] button not working in Intellij-Idea or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, printscreen

I'm using a thrid-party screen capturing application (Screenpresso). It's configured to start screen-capturing when I press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>. And indeed it works *except* when Intellij has Windows focus. In fact, to screen capture code I have to focus on *any other window* press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and then select the area within Intellij.

I've looked through all the settings, and especially the Keymap settings, and I can't see anything else that has been assigned to <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>. Of course, I'm not really sure; when I try to find a setting via [image: Find actions by shortcut] nothing happens, as pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> has no effect.

I know this used to work for me in previous versions of Intellij (though I can't remember what versions). But <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> used to work in Intellij just like every other application.

So I guess the question is, *why* is Intellij eating the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> keypress event? And can I turn it off so that the event gets correctly passed to my dedicated screen capturing application.

Intellij 2019.2.4 
Windows 10, 64b

Comment: I found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1140?p=IDEA-115742 which looks like there is indeed something fishy going on with the PrtSc keypress event since long. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: Related question, not quite a duplicate, I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421108/screenshots-with-idea-intellij

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Screenpresso:

https://www.screenpresso.com/support/hot-keys/

**Why shortcut [print screen] key does not always work?**

- This must be because you run your application with elevated
  privileges (with admin rights) (the UAC must have displayed a popup
  at startup).
- For security reasons, Screenpresso can handle shortcuts
  from Windows running with elevated privileges only when it is
  installed in Program Files folder.
- To fix this, you should install
  Screenpresso in Program Files folder which is not the default
  behavior:

  1. Uninstall Screenpresso
  2. Run again Screenpresso: Right click *Screenpresso.exe* and select **Run as administrator**
  3. Click on the **INSTALL on this computer** button while holding the **Control** key or click on the sub-menu **Install for all users**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it also helped me for ShareX - just make it run with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Some users have this problem, first reported 5 years ago: [Find here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115742)

Crash dumps (`java_error_in_*.log` in the user's home directory) can help to understand it better.